# JQM Flip toggle switch submit-function

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I like to use a jQuery mobile flip toggle switch to submit two status informations to control the two status of a relais.

Instead of using:

```
<input class="scene_btn" type="submit" onClick="request('key=1')" value="on" data-theme="d"</input>
<input class="scene_btn" type="submit" onClick="request('key=2')" value="off" data-theme="d"</input>
```

I'd like to use a jquery flip toggle switch, to switch on and off a relais.

```
<form>
<label for="flip-1">Flip toggle switch:</label>
<select name="flip-1" id="flip-1" data-role="slider">
    <option value="off">Off</option>
    <option value="on">On</option>
</select>
</form>
```

Does anybody know, how to to programm this?

Answer (score 1):

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/mC2ph/

#### HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>jQM Complex Demo</title>
        <meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=utf-8'/>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; minimum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=no; target-densityDpi=device-dpi"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.0-alpha.2/jquery.mobile-1.4.0-alpha.2.min.css"/>
        <!--<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>-->
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.0-alpha.2/jquery.mobile-1.4.0-alpha.2.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>     
        <div data-role="page" id="index" data-theme="a" >
            <div data-role="header">
                <h3>
                    First Page
                </h3>
                <a href="#second" class="ui-btn-right">Next</a>
            </div>

            <div data-role="content">
                <form id="test-form">
                    <label for="flip-1">Flip toggle switch:</label>
                    <select name="flip-1" id="flip-1" data-role="slider">
                        <option value="off">Off</option>
                        <option value="on">On</option>
                    </select>
                </form>      
            </div>

            <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">

            </div>
        </div> 
    </body>
</html>
```

#### JavaScript:

```
$(document).on('pageinit', '#index', function(){ 
    $(document).on( "slidestop",  "#flip-1" ,function( event, ui ) {
        console.log($("#flip-1").val());
        $('#test-form').submit();
    });       
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get solution here,

http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.2.0/docs/forms/switch/events.html

There is a specification about "Methods" and "event" so, it may be helpful for you.